# Could the potion protecting the horcrux have been drunk by multiple people?

Tags: harry-potter

After reading [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/8467/1234) question about the potion that protected the horcrux in the cave I got to wondering. Could multiple people have drank the potion in the cave, thus diluting its effect on any single person, while still permitting the horcrux to be retrieved?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's probable (nothing explicitly seems to contradict the idea), but likely not the case since it would have been considered unnecessary due to the restrictions on how many wizards could get onto the island via the boat:

> "It doesn't look like it was built for two people. Will it hold both of us? Will we be too heavy together?"
>
> Dumbledore chuckled. "Voldemort will not have cared about the weight, but about the amount of magical power that crossed his lake. I rather think an enchantment will have been placed upon this boat so that only one wizard at a time will be able to sail in it."

Comment: Well, a lot of muggles or squibs then.

Comment: @Xantec - the boat was also physically small.

Comment: Ingenious muggles and their outboard motors. Sounds like a math problem: if it takes 15 muggles and one wizard to successfully drink the potion and the boat will only hold 4 people, how many trips will need to be made to ferry everyone to the island with the horcrux?

Comment: @Xantec - I won't claim you can't break the system. Heck, V missed the house-elf apparation as well.

Comment: At this point, it really feels like Dumbledore's calling Harry a weakling. I mean, Dumbledore should qualify as having more magical power than the average "one wizard". Doesn't that imply that Harry is so weak that he actually *subtracts* from the total magical power in the boat?

Comment: @Yawus `if ($total_magical_field_in_boat) < 2) { boat_unlock() }`. Spot the bug in the above magical code.

Comment: Well, that depends. Well, we're looking at `if(Dumbledore.magical_field + Harry.magical_field < 2)`. The problem here: is `Dumbledore.magical_field > 2`? If so, then Harry's "magical field" has to be less than 0 to compensate.

Comment: @DVK missing left parens =P

Comment: @Steam More like he's referring to 'coming of age'; Harry was yet a full grown wizard. Much like he disregarded house elves as insignificant he did the same with children - and esp Harry though I suspect - with no proof either way - that he had already placed this Horcrux in the infamous cave before he heard the prophecy. So in fact he's not disregarding Harry at all; and later as they flee the cave he tells Harry that he's not worried because he has Harry with him (and Harry successfully apparates them both to Hogsmeade and obviously hadn't taken exam yet). He highly respects Harry!

Comment: @DVK-on-Ahch-To Although I can't take first credit with pointing out the error (though I didn't even need to be told there was an error as my programmer eyes pick up on it as I read it) I'd say the bug is actually in the compiler/interpreter. But if it can execute it's perhaps because Voldemort wrote a crappy compiler/interpreter. So he made the mistake of not accounting for more than one person but given that he assumed that it couldn't be circumvented it's very unlikely he didn't address more than one drinker. 1/2

Comment: @DVK-on-Ahch-To It seems you suggest it's probable that it could be done since he doesn't consider more than one person in the boat; and then you go on to say 'but likely not the case since it would have been considered unnecessary due to the restrictions'. But if he didn't consider that more than one person could get across he probably didn't consider that more than one person could drink it successfully since it'd be in his mind impossible. Of course no canon proof either way (that I know of) but that seems more plausible: underestimated the elves, not full-grown wizards and this too.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose so, because the potion was made for drinking, that was the problem. How many most likely didn't matter. Dumbledore just didn't want Harry to drink it just in case it was dangerous. It was more important that Harry lived than him, to Dumbledore. It was the boat that was made to ensure only one wizard, the potion was made to force the "thief/thieves" to drink it.