# Is there a reason why a Wizard and a bunch of Squibs couldn't get to Voldemort's locket Horcrux?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort

I was reading this question: [Could the potion protecting the horcrux have been drunk by multiple people?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8478/could-the-potion-protecting-the-horcrux-have-been-drunk-by-multiple-people)

And noticed a comment by Xantec: "Well, a lot of muggles or squibs then".

Is there an official reason in the book as to why that couldn't be done? Meaning, bring one Wizard and a team of non-wizards (or Squibs if you are worried about statute of secrecy) into the boat with you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yep, the book pretty clearly states that the boat was designed for two - 1 Wizard and one not.

From HP7 (When Kreacher recounts to the trio the circumstances of how he was used to place the Horcrux into the basin):

> “... There was a boat... “
>
> Of course there had been a boat; Harry knew the boat, ghostly green and tiny,
> **bewitched so as to carry one wizard and one victim toward the island in the center**. This,
> then, was how Voldemort had tested the defenses surrounding the Horcrux, by
> borrowing a disposable creature, a house-elf...

Comment: Whoah. That was some fast quoting. Are you Slytherincess in disguise? :)

Answer (score 5):

No, I don't think there is any good reason why not.  Yes the boat was only capable of carrying 2 people, but the wizard could make several trips taking one passenger at a time.  If they were capable of subjecting others to the torture of drinking that potion, then I'm sure they would be fine even using a spell to keep the muggles/squibs happy waiting whilst he does this.

However, I you would presume that Voldemort may have considered his defenses good enough:

1. You would have to be aware that Voldemort made horcruxes
2. You would have to be aware of the cave
3. You would have to know how to get into the cave, and the blood that is required
4. You would have to not stumble and touch the water once
5. You would have to have prepared in advance people to drink the potion for you, which would probably exclude many good wizards
6. And in any case this is only one of 7 horcruxes that you know you made.

Comment: Sorry, I meant "into the boat all at the same time". Valid points though  +1

Answer (score 0):

If you place anything other than the already existing boat in the water the Inferi would be aggravated.  I imagine trying to take multiple trips with the boat would likewise cause too much disruption in the waters.

Comment: Mojo, do you havea source for that?